# Serialize child collections with interfaces

Tags: c#, serialization, interface

I have an interface like so

```
public interface IA{
    IEnumerable<IB> Items {get;set;}
}

public interface IB{
    int ID {get;set;}
}
```

If I try to serialize the interface I get an error

```
Cannot serialize interface
```

If I create a concrete version of the interface, I can't create a concrete version of the collection.

```
public class classA:IA{
   public IEnumerable<B> Items {get;set;}  //this doesn't match the interface
}
```

but if I do the below we still have the serialization problem

```
public class classA:IA{
   public IEnumerable<IB> Items {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want an interface? A generic might help you with serializing IEnumerables of different types.

Answer (score 0):

The Serializable attribute cannot be inherited from a base class. Add it to child class and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot serialize an interface --- the computer isn't lying, you know ;-)

Try using concrete types.  Instead of `IEnumerable<IB>` try `List<object>` or an array.

HTH